# viewcontroller - how to get another root view controller / how to switch Views

Tags: ios, xcode4, viewcontroller

I'm having problems understanding where the object `viewController` comes from. I have an existing app that provides a detail view, and I need to put a table view in front of that to be able to choose a specific detail view. The app starts with

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

And I just don't get where `(self.)viewController` comes from. It's a property of my app delegate and it's in the `.m`-file of the app delegate:

```
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;
```

But I have no idea how the app knows, which `viewController` this is, because there seems to be no "assignment" or "creation" of the actual `viewController` object. And how would I move my tableView "in front" of the existing `viewController`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In nib-based projects there is a key in `Info.plist` named `NSMainNibFile`, or “Main nib file base name”, that instructs `UIApplication` to load `MainWindow.xib` and hook it into the app.

So if you look in `MainWindow.xib` (or whatever xib is referenced in the `Info.plist` `NSMainNibFile` entry), you'll see a view controller. If you click on the view controller in the document outline (panel on the left of the xib view), you can change it's class in the Identity Inspector (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, which pulls up the Identity Inspector in the right panel).

It's a little different with storyboards - the main nib key in `Info.plist` is now replaced with a main storyboard key, and the View Controllers now appear below each panel in the storyboard rather than in the document organizer - but it's basically the same idea.

The xib/storyboard file is compiled to code that allocs a `UIViewController` instance at startup and assigns the instance to the `viewController` variable.